# Click on record from a form to go to associated record in same form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Looking for a way to click on a record in a form and then have it go to another record in the same form.

Example: There's a form that lists Products and associated records along with that product. One of the records is a "Replaced" field. Which will show what past Products it replaced.

I want to be able to click in the Replaced field and have it go to that Product record.

```
txtProduct: Iphone6
txtReplaced: Iphone5 (click on Iphone5) -> and then shows

txtProduct: Iphone5
txtReplaced: Iphone4
```

I looked into GoToRecord and FindRecord. Thinking the best way to go about it is to put vba code into the On Click event procedure using one of those for txtReplaced. Just not sure how to do that

EDIT to include attempt using RecordsetClone. It's now giving me the error that it can't find the record when I know it's there. Any insight on what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Sub txtSupersedes_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Dim rs As Object
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "[Model]='" & Me.txtSupersedes.Value & "'"
If rs.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, could not find Model '" & txtSupersedes & "' ", vbOKOnly, vbInformation
Else
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If
rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Research use of RecordsetClone for going to a record without filtering.

Comment: Made some progress with your suggestion, updated my original post with what I have so far.

Comment: Declaring and setting a recordset object is not actually necessary but it should work. I see nothing wrong with syntax and logic. It works for me. Assuming Model is a text type field.

Comment: Figured it out. I was using a subform and not referring to the parent form. So it was searching the subform, reason why it kept saying Model not found. Thanks for setting me down the correct path

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub txtSupersedes_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

Dim rs As Object
Dim txtValue As String

txtValue = Me![txtSupersedes].Value


With Me.Parent.Form

    Set rs = .RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[Model]= '" & txtValue & "'"
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, could not find Model '" & txtSupersedes & "' ", vbOKOnly, vbInformation
    Else
        .Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If
    rs.Close

End With

End Sub
```